# How to find text in jsonb in all fields using graphQl query

Tags: postgresql, graphql, jsonb, hasura

I have Table in postgresql with two columns id(int) and data(jsonb)

```
id  | data
---------
int | jsonb
```

data has undefined format for example

```
{ id: 0, name: "Sergey", age: 23} or {vehicle: "motorcycle", max_speed: 250, brand: "honda"}
```

I need to write qraphQl query where response contains data list where find key word in any jsonb fields for example:

```
query {
  declarations(where: {data: {_ilike: "Sergey"}}) {
    id
    data
  }
}
```

But at this case I have error:
"message": "field '_ilike' not found in type: 'jsonb_comparison_exp'"

Comment: Which framework do you use for graphql api implementation? Some frameworks provide `contains` operation: `where: {data: {contains: "Sergey"}}`

Comment: @Eugene I use hasura. But execute query from C++ code

Comment: Then check `_contains` operation: `where: {data: {_contains: "Sergey"}}`. I got it from the docs: https://hasura.io/docs/latest/queries/postgres/query-filters/#jsonb-operators-_contains-_has_key-etc

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work because $jsonFilter: jsonb must be jsonb, but I need to use string. And in your example you exactly know key, but in my case I can not know about key

Answer (score 0):

I need to use user's function in postgresql.

1. Create function

   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.new_function1()
   RETURNS SETOF declarations
   LANGUAGE sql
   STABLE
   AS $function$
   select * from declarations where data @? '$.** ? (@ == "Sergey")';
   $function$
2. Track this function into data base
3. Use this function in graphQl

   query {
   new_function1() {
   data
   }
   }